# App funciona en emulador pero no en el movil

Tags: php, mysql, android

Es una prueba sencilla de registro y login a base de datos `MySQL` que funciona correctamente en el emulador pero al probarla en el teléfono via usb se ejecuta pero no responde a vincularse con la base de datos.

Este es el código en java para el registro:

```
package com.example.registrobienvenida;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL="http://192.168.1.XX/RegistroBienvenida/Register.php";
    private Map<String,String> params;

    public RegisterRequest(String password, String usuario, String apellido, String nombre, String mail, String movil, Response.Listener<String> listener){
       super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
       params = new HashMap<>();
       params.put("password", password);
       params.put("usuario", usuario);
       params.put("apellido", apellido);
       params.put("nombre", nombre);
       params.put("mail", mail);
       params.put("movil", movil);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Y este es el php que funciona como `Webservice`:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "prueba_registros");

    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $usuario = $_POST["username"];
    $apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $mail = $_POST["mail"];
    $movil = $_POST["movil"];
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO usuarios (password, username, apellido, nombre, mail, movil) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssssss", $password, $username, $apellido, $nombre, $mail, $movil);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

> La base de datos está en mi pc, creada con `MySQL`.
>
> En lugar de `localhost`, en android puse la ip (la `XX` no va es otro
>   número).
>
> El emulador funciona Ok.
>
> En el telefono no sale error alguno pero es como que no se conecta.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Hola, tu base de datos la levantas en el teléfono? O en tu pc de desarrollo tienes la base de datos y te conectas por el emulador a ella?, si es así lo que tienes que hacer es estar en la misma red e intentar conectarte, prueba a configurar los puertos en tu equipo local para que permita verlo en la red.

Comment: seria genial que muestres el codigo que usas para conectarte a la base de datos...!

Comment: Primeramente pon los logs que te muestra Android studio y de ahí avanzamos

Comment: @RaulZarate como se configuran los puertos?

Comment: Tienes que abrir los puertos de Mysql en el firewall de tu computadora, para que lo puedas ver en la red, te estoy entendiendo entonces que es una aplicación local que vas a correr en la misma red, verifica en la configuración de tu Mysql en que puerto realiza peticiones, tambíen verifica en tu router que esos mismos puertos no están bloqueados, con eso debería funcionar.

Comment: @RaulZarate El firewall de la computadora tiene tanto a MySQL como a Apache como aplicaciones permitidas de comunicarse y en configuraciones avanzadas Apache HTTP Server y mysqld tienen Puerto Local y Remoto cualquiera (En reglas de entrada). El router ni idea como verificarlo. El celular no podra ser?

Comment: Dudo que sea el celular... a menos que tengas algun antivirus que tenga reglas, pero lo dudo...

Comment: Otra cosa que tienes que verificar es el nivel de acceso del usuario a la base de datos, En el mysql workbech, entras en administración, luego a usuarios y privilegios y asigna al usuario con el que te conectas: % que te permite conectarte desde cualquier locación que tenga acceso a la base de datos, tanto equipo local como de red.

Comment: @RaulZarate Agregue permisos a los puertos 80, 443 y 3306 en reglas de entrada del firewall de windows. Tambien hize lo que sugeriste en el mysql. Y por ultimo probe con la red del celu mediante Mobile Hotspot y no funciona.

Comment: Deshabilita el firewall en la computadora, haz tu prueba, sino también en el módem, esperemos te funcione, sino puede ser otra cosa, checa que la aplicación apunte a la ip del equipo que tiene la base de datos, en la conexión no iría "localhost" ehh? porque veo que eso tienes en el mysql connect... checa esto primero... si lo tienes así no deshabilites el firewall ni nada.

Comment: @RaulZarate Esto es lo ultimo que hice: Desconecte la notebook de la red de internet de mi casa, me conecte a la red Mobile Hotspot del celular, deshabilite el firewall de W10, verifique ipconfig y modifique localhost por la IP, tambien probe netstat -an y los puertos 80,443 y 3306 que usan Apache y MySQL estaban abiertos. Corri la app desde el emulador y funciono, lo hice desde el celular y no funiciona, como agregue un Toast puedo ver el error: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError:java.io.IOException:Cleartext HTTP traffic to 192.168.43.217 not permitted. No se que mas hacer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solucionado el problema. Mi celular es un Samsung Galaxy S8 y sorpresa tiene Android 9 y se debe habilitar el CleartextTraffic ya que segun la documentacion de Android Studio: Android 9: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted.
Se debe agregar al Manifest lo siguiente: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" y problema solucionado.

Comment: Excelente, es un gusto haberte ayudado, aunque la solución haya sido otra, no olvides dar detalles completos cuando vuelvas a preguntar. Saludos!

Comment: mmm esa linea de codigo ya la tengo y aun asi no registra los datos desde mi celular